# Regular expression to match EOF

Tags: regex

I have some data that look like this:

```
john, dave, chris
rick, sam, bob
joe, milt, paul
```

I'm using this regex to match the names:

```
/(\w.+?)(\r\n|\n|,)/
```

Which works for the most part, but the file ends abruptly after the last word, meaning the last value doesn't end in `\r\n`, `\n` or `,`. It ends with EOF. Is there a way to match EOF in regex so I can put it right in that second grouping?

Comment: Are you trying to capture all the names in one group or one capture group per name?

Comment: one thing to do when having trouble with regex is to try elements of you pattern in isolation.  if you are concerned about the token at the end, test your expression without it.

Comment: just wanted to add a great regex testing site: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171284/regex-to-match-eof

Comment: @Sinan - I agree; merged

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The answer to this question is `\Z` took me awhile to figure it out, but it works now. Note that conversely, `\A` matches beginning of the whole string (as opposed to `^` and `$` matching the beginning of one line).

[Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):
`\Z` Match absolute string end

[Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds), [C# (.NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#anchors), [PHP](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC10), [Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref#ANCHORS):
`\Z` Match string end (before last newline if present)
`\z` Match absolute string end

[Go](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp/syntax):
`\z` Match absolute string end

All of the above:
`\A` Match absolute string start

Comment: Just a heads up if you are after such fonctionality in netbeans for a **project files search** as opposed to an **in file search**, the following will behave differently... `(\s*)\?>(\s*)\Z` ... and after some more digging here is what would work on a project folder: `(\s*)\?>(\s*)(\n*)(\W)\Z`  FYI: this is to replace all closing php tags by line breaks at end of file.

Comment: Turns out `\A` also works in Visual Studio find and replace. As always use such things with caution but it saved me a ton of manual messing about once I was happy it would actually do the right thing.

Comment: While I am using Java's `Scanner` class to read an entire file at once; if I use `\Z` as delimiter, trailing newline character trimmed. When I changed delimiter to `\z`, trailing newline character preserved. It seems that [Martin Dorey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13651321/471214) also applies to Java.

Answer (score 36):

You can find EOF like so: `$(?![\r\n])`. This works whether your line endings are CR, CRLF, or just LF. Works in Visual Studio, VS Code, Python, Java, C#, JavaScript & PHP, but not Go.

As a bonus, in Visual Studio, you can ensure all your code files have a final newline marker like so:

```
               Find What: (?<![\r\n])$(?![\r\n])
            Replace With: \r\n
 Use Regular Expressions: checked
Look at these file types: *.cs, *.cshtml, *.js
```

How this works:

Find any line end (a zero-width match) that is not preceded by CR or LF, and is also not followed by CR or LF. Some thought will show you why this works!

Note that you should Replace With your desired line-ending character, be it CR, LF, or CRLF.

Comment: There's a bug in Visual Studio 2019 where doing a replace all with this can result in two newlines being added to the end of the file. I think it has something to do with the auto-insert newline on save option.

Comment: @Stevoisiak That *might* be caused by inserting the wrong newline pattern. E.g., i your IDE is looking for `\r\n` and you only put in `\n`, it may fail to detect the "two newlines".

Comment: This also works with JavaScript (including Node.js) and VS Code (of course, since it uses JS for regex).

Comment: `(?=\n?$(?![\r\n]))` emulates `\Z`, match absolute string end (before final newline if present) (`\Z` is available in Java, C# (.NET), PHP & Perl). If you're confident your input only uses `\n`, you can simplify these to `$(?!\n)` (`\z`) and  `(?=\n?$(?!\n))`  (`\Z`)

Answer (score 28):

EOF is not actually a character. If you have a multi-line string, then '$' will match the end of the string as well as the end of a line.

In Perl and its brethren, `\A` and `\Z` match the beginning and end of the string, totally ignoring line-breaks.

GNU extensions to POSIX regexes use `` \` `` and `\'` for the same things.

Comment: Some systems (DOS/Windows) use control-z as an end of file character.  I found this out the hard way processing some old data (or data generated by an old program).

Answer (score 12):

Contrast the behavior of [Ryan's suggested \Z with \z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171284/regular-expression-to-match-eof/1171300#1171300):

```
$ perl -we 'my $corpus = "hello\n"; $corpus =~ s/\Z/world/g; print(":$corpus:\n")'
:helloworld
world:

$ perl -we 'my $corpus = "hello\n"; $corpus =~ s/\z/world/g; print(":$corpus:\n")'
:hello
world:
```

[perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) sez:

```
\Z  Match only at end of string, or before newline at the end
\z  Match only at end of string
```

A translation of the test case into Ruby (1.8.7, 1.9.2) behaves the same.

In a comment, [mmdemirbas adds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171284/regex-to-match-eof#comment85267755_1171300) that Java is the same.

Answer (score 11):

As JavaScript RegEx doesn't support the boundary match for final terminator (`\Z`), you could use the following:

```
var matchEndOfInput = /$(?![\r\n])/gm;
```

Basically this would match the end of the line, which is not followed by carriage return or new line characters. In essence it behaves the same way as `\Z` and can be used with JavaScript RegEx implementation.

Comment: `var matchBeginInput = /^(?<![\r\n])/gm;` (JavaScript RegEx equivalent of `\A` or opposite of EOF)

Comment: (Uses a negative lookbehind assertion.)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to capture the line separators, this regex should be all you need:

```
/\w+/
```

That's assuming all the substrings you want to match consist entirely of word characters, like in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try $ (EOL/EOF) instead of (\r\n|\n)?

```
/\"(.+?)\".+?(\w.+?)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using proper modifier forcing to treat string as a whole (not line-by-line - and if \n works for you, you are using it), just add another alternative - end of string: (\r\n|\n|,|$)

Answer (score 0):

`/(\w.+?)(\r\n|\n|,|$)/`

Answer (score 0):

If lookahead and lookbehind are supported by the regex engine you're using, use:

- `(?<![\r\n])^` to emulate `\A`, match absolute string start.
  (`\A` is available in Python, Java, C#, PHP & Go)
- `$(?![\r\n])` to emulate `\z`, match absolute string end.
  (`\z` is available in Java, C# (.NET), PHP, Perl & Go. In Python, `\Z` behaves like `\z`)
- `(?=[\r\n]?$(?![\r\n]))` to emulate `\Z`, match string end (before final newline if present).
  (`\Z` is available in Java, C# (.NET), PHP & Perl. In Python, `\Z` behaves like `\z`)

If all of your line endings are `\n`, you can simplify the above to:

- `\A`: `(?<!\n)^`
- `\z`: `$(?!\n)`
- `\Z`: `(?=\n?$(?!\n))`

Note: **JavaScript** has always supported lookahead (used for `\z` & `\Z` emulation above), but lookbehind (used for `\A` emulation above) support is newer, and still limited due to Safari / WebKit, see [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) and [bugs.webkit.org](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174931) for details. Node.js has had lookbehind support since [v9](https://node.green/#ES2018-features--RegExp-Lookbehind-Assertions).