# Matching the list with Regex

Tags: regex

I want to parse the following statement using regex:

```
(o) Multi
line
text
(o) Single line text
(o) Single line text
```

When I use the following regex, the whole text of the source is captured:

```
(?<bullet>\(o\)\ ) (?<text>.+)
```

What I want to achieve is having three matches of `text` group, ie.

```
Multi
line
text
```

and then twice `Single line text`.

If the solution is lookahead/behind, how to use it to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use lookahead to check for the next (o) or end of input

`(?<bullet>\(o\)) (?<text>.*?)(?=\(o\)|$)`

Comment: Works like a charm. But what does the question mark after the asterisk mean?

Comment: That means its lazy or ungreedy, basically it says it will take the smallest amount of text matched. you can read about it here http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add a (o) or EOF at the end of your regex so it will cut at the next bullet or the end of the file. I don't know which kind of regex are you using to give you the exact regex but the idea is to match that.

Here it's how to match EOF in normal regex: 
[regex to match EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171284/regex-to-match-eof)

Answer (score 0):

Why use a regex at all? Seems like you have two cases - A line starts with a bullet or it doesn't.  If is starts with a bullet, cut that off and start a new text object with the rest of the line.  If it doesn't start with a bullet, append that text to the previous text object.  In pseudocode:

```
text = []
i = -1
for line in data:
    if line.starts_with('(o)'):
        i += 1
        text[i] = line[2:]  # all characters in the line after the first three
    else:
        text[i].append(line)
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work, but I specifically need to use regex.

Comment: Unfortunate.  I consider regular expressions a write only language, and thus try to keep all but the simplest of regexes as a tool of last resort.  Please at least put some clear comments around the regex so when you come back to it in six months, you don't need to decode it.