# How to match everything in certain bounds using regexp in go?

Tags: regex, go, parsing

My goal is to get the contents of a go function.

Starting from `func` till the last curly brace `}`.

Currently i can get the function name using below code:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`func (.*) `)
```

but i want to get the whole contents of the function.

Tried with:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`func (.s)`)
```

but this isn't working, need to get all the content with newlines till the last curly brace at the end of the function.

**EDIT:**
Manage to get the functions using this regex:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`func(.*?)[\s\S]+?(func|\z)`)
```

but only problem is that it is getting half of the functions(may be due to second `func`). Is there a way to tweak this regex to get all of the functions?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, you can instruct a regex to stop at the first `}` it sees but what you wan't is to count how many `{` you have seen and stop when you find the `}` that matches the `func {`. Regexes can't do this for you.

Instead, read the file line by line and maintain a counter, increment for each `{` and decrement for each `}` util you hit 0.

Or use an actual parser like [go/parser](https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser).

Comment: thanks! for the answer, i kinda manage to figure this out but somehow i manage to get the contents of the function too using this regex `func(.*?)[\s\S]+?func{0,1}` but only problem with it is i cant get the contents of the last function or if there is only one function :(. So i am wondering if there's any possible way to get the EOF using regex?

Comment: ah found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171284/regular-expression-to-match-eof will see if it will work.